# why is 'mouseleave' not triggered when triggering 'mouseenter' programmatically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm writing a Next.JS app, and creating a useHover() hook to handle hover events via Javascript by using 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave' events, and
I noticed that when I triggering 'mouseenter' programmatically:

```
let mouseenter = new Event('mouseenter');
refElement.current.dispatchEvent(mouseenter);
```

'mouseleave' event is not triggered anymore automatically (which I need for my logic) after leaving the element.
Why tho? Am I missing something? BTW all listeners are set correctly, everythings (mouse events) work as intended when not triggering programmatically, but for some reason, manual triggering break automatic 'mouseleave'.

Comment: Why would it be if neither the user nor your did anything that would trigger it? (Roughly speaking, the Event object you create is just a JS object and just passed through various functions; it doesn't mean "pretend that the user did this").

Comment: ah ok so my event does no represent the acuat 'mouseenter' event?  if so how can I simulate that event?

Comment: You can simply dispatch the `mouseleave` event as well.

Comment: I know I can trigger the mouseleave, but my question is to understand the reason why mouseleave is not triggered (whenever the pointer does actually leave the element) in case the mouseenter is triggered programmatically in the first place, whereas mouseleave  works as intended when mouseenter is NOT triggered programmatically.

Comment: Interestingly, it works okay [here](https://jsbin.com/vedeyayaba/edit?css,js,console,output)

Comment: acually not, because mouseenter is triggered the first time via code (hence the first 'in' printed) , but when you click/get outside the square, does not trigger the mouseleave :(, this is the perfect snippet to represent my question btw

Comment: The `mouseenter` event is triggered programmatically but the cursor isn't actually inside the div. Clicking/moving outside without actually moving the cursor inside will not trigger the `mouseleave` event.